# AWS Synthetics Canary for internal ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am looking to create a canary to monitor one of our internal applications. For this purpose I created a canary of type API and have the following script

```
var synthetics = require('Synthetics');
const log = require('SyntheticsLogger');
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');

const apiCanaryBlueprint = async function () {
    const postData = "";

    const verifyRequest = async function (requestOption) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        log.info("Making request with options: " + JSON.stringify(requestOption));
        let req
        if (requestOption.port === 443) {
          req = https.request(requestOption);
        } else {
          req = http.request(requestOption);
        }
        req.on('response', (res) => {
          log.info(`Status Code: ${res.statusCode}`)
          log.info(`Response Headers: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`)
          //If the response status code is not a 2xx success code
          if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode > 299) {
             reject("Failed: " + requestOption.path);
          }
          res.on('data', (d) => {
            log.info("Response: " + d);
          });
          res.on('end', () => {
            resolve();
          })
        });

        req.on('error', (error) => {
          reject(error);
        });

        if (postData) {
          req.write(postData);
        }
        req.end();
      });
    }

    const headers = {}
    headers['User-Agent'] = [synthetics.getCanaryUserAgentString(), headers['User-Agent']].join(' ');
    const requestOptions = {"hostname":"company-alb.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com","method":"GET","path":"","port":443}
    requestOptions['headers'] = headers;
    await verifyRequest(requestOptions);
};

exports.handler = async () => {
    return await apiCanaryBlueprint();
};
```

I have added the appropriate VPC , subnets and security groups while creating the canary as confifured for the above ALB, but the script times out trying to access the API, what else am I missing? Notice that the `hostname` provided in the script is the Elastic load balancer A record DNS name

Comment: if things are hanging, then you probably have a network connectivity issue, double check your routing, subnets and SGs.  Can you provide information to show that these are all setup and there is an allowed route between the two?

Comment: while creating the canary it asked me to provide vpc, subnet and sg which I did, is there a way i can verify connectivity between these two?